# Is 'not defined' falsy or nothing?

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

This is making me angry:
If I don't do this:

```
var a;
```

And then do this:

```
if(a){
    // doing stuff
}
```

It spits out this error:

```
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

So how can I check if a variable is defined!

Please don't tell me to use `typeof`.

EDIT:

`a` is defined by a library sometimes.  I want to check if the library defined it so if not I define it so I can still use it in my code!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use `typeof`?

Comment: @colin - I already know hoe to use it in this instance.  I'm looking for a better, easier way.

Comment: Why would you be teting the variable if you've never defined it? How can the if statement know what it is checking if it isn't defined? You need to define and populate variables.. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: If you're getting a ReferenceError, your variable is out of scope.

Comment: [works fine?](http://jsfiddle.net/H6BC2/) or do you mean you are not declaring a?

Comment: Why would your code need to check whether "a" is defined?  Surely you know.  Or are you checking for a **global** variable?  If that, then you can do: `if (window.a) { ... }`

Comment: @musefan - I mean I'm not declaring it. It's declared by a library I'm using.

Comment: PitaJ: If it's from a different library, that means it's global, so you'd use the `window.a` method that @Pointy shows in his comment.

Comment: @amnotiam - It's not always declared by that library.  Check the EDIT in my question

Comment: PitaJ: who cares? You'd still use @Pointy's solution to check for it.

Comment: Oh also note that `if (window.a)` just checks for falsiness, which is probably OK if the symbol is something like `jQuery` or `$`, and you know that it's either an object reference or nothing.

Comment: *"Please don't tell me to use `typeof`."* ... why not? That's the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure the `a` is declared, and not causing any reference error problem. You may  add a re-declaration statement.

```
var a = a;
```

In this case, if a is defined, nothing changes, otherwise it's undefined.

NOTICE: this only works when `a` is in global scope, check out comments for more details.

Comment: I don't think this will actually work due to the hoisting of `var` declarations.  It'll always leave "a" set to `undefined`.

Comment: This is sort of interesting, however if op is attempting to use a global variable `a` (I'm not sure op is or isn't) then doing this will create a variable `a` in the local scope, and as such any modifications to it won't affect the global instance.  The correct way to do this is mentioned in other answers here: `if(typeof a === 'undefined'){...}`, regardless if op wants to hear that or not.  :)

Comment: @Madbreaks, you are right. But as he is looking for an alternative, I think this is acceptable.

Comment: @Pointy this works actually. Though I won't do this in my code.

Comment: I suppose it will work if the test is made in the global scope, because if it's already defined then the `var` is a no-op.

Comment: Since this answer was accpeted, you should make clear that this only works if the `var a = a;` code is running in the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

Check for undefined withut throwing ReferneceError like so:

```
if (typeof window.a == "undefined") {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: That will cause a Reference Error if "a" is actually not defined.

Comment: Sorry I was speaking in generality (using x).  I have updated my example to reflect use of 'a' as variable name.

Comment: Doesn't matter. This'll still cause the ReferenceError noted in the question if `a` is not declared. The solution is to declare variables before using them.

Comment: @musefan it's unwritable in the latest spec.

Comment: @musefan: If `undefined` is defined, then you have some hostile code that needs to be removed. There should be no such "what if" allowed in your environment.

Comment: @xiaoyi: interesting to know... just 5 years to wait for browser reliability then? :D

Comment: @amnotiam: hostile code like not knowing if some library creates a variable called 'a' or not?

Comment: @musefan: so true! That's why some coders will declare their own `undefined` variable.

Comment: @musefan: Huh? No, hostile as in the redefinition of the global `undefined`. Whatever code is doing it needs to be removed.

Comment: @amnotiam: Yes I agree with that, it would be bad code. But I also see that using a library that may or may not have a variable available to query is also a bit suspect

Comment: @musefan: I'd agree with that. Although the situation may be that OP is going to load a library only if it isn't already loaded. Like testing for the global `jQuery`.

Comment: @xiaoyi: I have read about defining undefined manually to ensure the correct value is used. However, I have a habit of knowing when to expect a variable to be defined or not anyway so never need to check this.... yet ;)

Comment: @amnotiam: ok, you may be on to something there ;)

Comment: Modified original response to make remove reference error. This would only work for testing a variable in global scope.

Comment: @MikeBrant: It's still not correct, `typeof` **always** returns a string. You have to compare with `"undefined"`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes. I did not change that when I modified my original text.  I have modified it above.

Comment: It's a common mistake that leads to bugs, which is part of the reason why such unnatural syntax is better avoided.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this

```
if(typeof a!='undefined')
{
    // a is defined
}
else
{
    // a is not defined
}
```

**Update:** Alternatively you can use

```
if(a==void 0) // undefined
```

Comment: I know I can use this but I just don't want to! I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: @amnotiam Pls, can you provide a link to "It's hackish, error prone and unnecessary" ?

Comment: @Engineer: Look at the current state of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11654313/1106925). `typeof window.a == undefined` It is a very very common example of how this unnatural syntax breaks. I've given a very detailed answer to this in the past, but people who don't read and think just downvoted, so I removed it from the community.

Comment: @amnotiam What if `a` defined like `var a=true;` and not like `window.a=true;` in global scope?  The `typeof window.a !== undefined` will be failed,but `typeof a !== undefined` will not.

Comment: @Engineer: No it won't. If you do `var a = "foo"` in global scope, `a` becomes a property of `window`. http://jsfiddle.net/9pyDD/ ...and again `typeof window.a == undefined` is the wrong syntax.

Comment: Sheikh Heera: Your update will cause a *ReferenceError* if `a` has not been declared. That's the point of the question.

Comment: @amnotiam hmm, yes it is not failed. But however I don't understand the  usage of `window`.

Comment: @Engineer: `window` is the object that holds the variables of the global lexical environment. Every nested lexical environment has such an object as well, but they're not directly accessible as an object. Only the global environment exposes it and allows it to be directly manipulated. That said... you don't have total control. If you declare `var a` globally, you can't remove `a` by doing `delete window.a`, but it'll work if you declared it as `window.a`.

Comment: @amnotiam, you are right and in that case `typeof` is the better way I think.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
if( !window.hasOwnProperty('a') ){    
    window.a = 'some definition here';
}
```